# Is there a way to set the default TTL for multicast packets at system level?

Tags: centos, multicast

pcap capture from my Centos 7 to multicast address shows TTL 25. Firewall considered it as DDOS and dropped packets.

I know that application code can set the multicast TTL with a call to setsockopt() with the flag IP_MULTICAST_TTL, stating further that default value is 1. I want to know if there is a way to set that value at the system level.

Only tunable parameter I found is net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl, but changing it, would change the ttl for entire IP stack and wouldn't be specific to multicast packets only.

Any advice on this ? Thanks

---

Editing for additional information asked in comment --> Application is not working. As per network guys, their firewall conside this DDOS attack and dropping packets. To fix this, they suggested to reduce multicast TTL from current 25 to 10 or lower.
As per application guy, they did not enforce this in their application and want me to enforce from system/OS level. But I can't find any tunable parameter at OS level, which can do this.

Comment: Application guy lied. Either it's not multicast, or they did explicitly change the multicast TTL from 1 to an other value. Pick the lie.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (as root) /etc/sysctl.conf, or on some distros you can create a new sysctl file.
Assuming you'd like a ttl of 99, add a line with the following contents ....
"net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=99"
For example ...

```
echo net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=99 | sudo tee /etc//etc/sysctl.d/42-myttl.conf
```

You can read/write the current system default ttl with the syctl command as

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 64
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=99
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 99
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 99
```

Comment: As I read it will update the IP TTL (net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 1), however it would change the ttl for entire ip stack and wouldn't be specific to multicast packets only. Am I correct on this?
I just want to update TTL for multicast.